# Python how to access list item with a variable

Tags: python

I searched for this for a while tonight, but I didn't find anything... or maybe I'm too noob to understand?
Well here's my code, the question will follow, I think that you'll understand it better if I show you the code now:

```
lencount = 1
decrypted = []
while lencount <= length:
    if intlist[lencount] == 2:
    print('OK!')
    decrypted.append(alphabet[2])
    lencount += 1
print(decrypted)
```

Here's the whole code, if you want to see:

```
import os
# os.system("multimon-ng -a dtmf -q | grep -x -E '[0-9]+' --line-buffered >> $HOME/dtmf.txt")
file=open('/home/nicolasmailloux/dtmf.txt')
line=file.read()
text = line.replace("\n", "")
n = 2
chars = [c for c in text]
ngrams = []
for i in range(len(chars)-n + 1):
  ngram = "".join(chars[i:i+n])
  ngrams.append(ngram)
intlist = list(map(int, ngrams))
length = int(len(intlist))
print(length)
print(intlist)
# Defining some variables
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
lencount = 1
decrypted = []
while lencount <= length:
    if intlist[lencount] == 2:
        print('OK!')
        decrypted.append(alphabet[2])
    lencount += 1
print(decrypted)
```

The thing is that the amount of items in the lists is variable and I can't access it (why??) by using a variable in `intlist[lencount]`. This is confusing. Here's the output I have when I try to run the program:

```
    if intlist[lencount] == 2:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: edited; you can now see my whole program

Comment: Guess: `length = len(intlist)` and therefore `<=` in `lencount <= length` should be set to `<`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because the [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) function returns:

> The length (the number of items) of an object.

However, lists are zero-indexed in Python, meaning that `some_list[len(some_list)]` will always be out of range, because `len()` does not take zero-indexing into account.

Because of this, the conditional `while lencount <= length` allows `intlist[len(intlist)]` to occur, which by definition is out of range. This can be solved with the following:

```
while lencount < length:
    if intlist[lencount] == 2:
        print('OK!')
...
```

Additionally, assuming you want to go through all values of `intlist`, `lencount` should be initialized to 0, so:

```
lencount = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

```
length = int(len(intlist))
```

in combination with

```
while lencount <= length:
    if intlist[lencount] == 2:
```

`lencount=length` is out of range (indices go from `0, ..., len(list)-1`).

Answer (score 0):

lencount = 1

problem is your lencount starting with 1

your while loop is something like that,

lencount = 30
if intlist[31] == 2:

but inlist len is 30,

you are trying to find index 31